# Why are interrupts needed for MMIO on pcie?

Tags: linux, arm, kernel, driver, interrupt

This blog post talks about the difficulties in bringing pci passtrhough support for ARM devices: https://www.linaro.org/blog/kvm-pciemsi-passthrough-armarm64/

It cies GICv2/GICv3 which are ARM's interrupt controllers. You can write to it via MMIO and make it deliver interrupts to CPUs.

However, why interrupts are needed? Shouldn't the PCIe driver talk with the PCIe device through MMIO. That is, writing/reading from memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is necessary because otherwise the operating-system doesn't have any way of knowing an event happened. Operating-systems are not polling memory constantly. They still need to know that an event happened and when. That's where interrupts come in.

Imagine you have an hard-disk PCIe controller. How does the operating-system know when the disk is done writing its data to RAM?